# Phone view on chrome inspection is messing up the dimensions on certain pages for my site

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, web-inspector

So I've been working on the responsiveness for my website I'm making and everything works just fine when im on the home page. But when I switch to any other page the dimension for some reason don't register and it says the size of the page is way bigger than it actually is (i have it set to iphone view(375x667) but it keeps saying (980x1743)). Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

[image: This is an example of the sizing being messed up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dimensions of your website are being messed up when viewed in the Chrome DevTools device emulator, try the following steps:

- Check the viewport meta tag in the HTML head section of your website.
- Check for any CSS issues using the Chrome DevTools Elements panel.
- Disable any browser extensions that may be causing issues.
- Try using a different device emulator or a different browser to view your website.